# Read line output in a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I want to run a program (when executed it produces logdata) out of a shell script and write the output into a text file. I failed to do so :/

$prog is the executed prog -> `socat /dev/ttyUSB0,b9600 STDOUT`

$log/$FILE is just path to a .txt file

I had a Perl script to do this:

```
open (S,$prog) ||die "Cannot open $prog ($!)\n";
open (R,">>","$log") ||die "Cannot open logfile $log!\n";

while (<S>) {
    my $date = localtime->strftime('%d.%m.%Y;%H:%M:%S;');
    print "$date$_";
}
```

I tried to do this in a shell script like this

```
#!/bin/sh

FILE=/var/log/mylogfile.log

SOCAT=/usr/bin/socat
DEV=/dev/ttyUSB0
BAUD=,b9600
PROG=$SOCAT $DEV$BAUD STDOUT

exec 3<&0
exec 0<$PROG
while read -r line
do
        DATE=`date +%d.%m.%Y;%H:%M:%S;`
        echo $DATE$line >> $FILE
done
exec 0<&3
```

Doesn't work at all...

How do I read the output of that prog and pipe it into my text file using a shell script? What did I do wrong (if I didn't do everything wrong)?

---

Final code:

```
#!/bin/sh

FILE=/var/log/mylogfile.log

SOCAT=/usr/bin/socat
DEV=/dev/ttyUSB0
BAUD=,b9600
CMD="$SOCAT $DEV$BAUD STDOUT"

$CMD |
while read -r line
do
    echo "$(date +'%d.%m.%Y;%H:%M:%S;')$line" >> $FILE
done
```

Comment: You need to show a lot more of the code. I assume `$prog` is the piped output from a program? There must also be a `use Time::Piece` in there?

Comment: You've not shown where you set `$FILE` — was that `$log` in the Perl? (Nor have you shown where you set `$prog`).  Why don't you use `exec >>$FILE` so all the output is appended to the log file (or you can use `exec >$FILE` if you want to zap the file in this script)?

Comment: @Borodin the perlscript is not the problem, it works fine. but since its not my script it has alot more crap in it that I dont need and dont understand. I just need the simple little part that I just posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To read from a process, use process substitution

```
exec 0< <( $PROG )
```

`/bin/sh` doesn't support it, so use `/bin/bash` instead.

To assign several words to a variable, quote or backslash whitespace:

```
PROG="$SOCAT $DEV$BAUD STDOUT"
```

Semicolon is special in shell, quote it or backslash it:

```
DATE=$(date '+%d.%m.%Y;%H:%M:%S;')
```

Moreover, no exec's are needed:

```
while ...
    ...
done < <( $PROG )
```

You might even add `> $FILE` after `done` instead of adding each line separately to the file.

Comment: @CodingMonkey: Updated.

Comment: Thanks for the help. done < < ( $PROG ) causes Syntax error: redirection unexpected.
The final code is in the first post

Comment: @CodingMonkey: No space between `<` and `(`!

Comment: sorry, just wrote it here because I had the error copied. In the script I had it without that space, didnt work

Comment: @CodingMonkey: Use `/bin/bash`, not `/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 0):

#### Original answer

You haven't shown the error messages — which would have been helpful.

Your problem, though, is probably this line:

```
DATE=`date +%d.%m.%Y;%H:%M:%S;`
```

where the semicolons mark the end of a command, and there likely isn't a command `%H` that does anything useful, etc.

You need quotes around the format argument to `date`, and I'd use single quotes for this job:

```
DATE=$(date +'%d.%m.%Y;%H:%M:%S;')
```

or even replace the two lines in the body of the loop with:

```
echo "$(date +'%d.%m.%Y;%H:%M:%S;')$line" >> $FILE
```

The double quotes prevent a variety of problems.

That assumes you fix a bunch of other problems, such as the setting of the variables `FILE` and `prog`.  Also, I'd probably use:

```
exec > $FILE
```

to initially zap the output file and then all subsequent standard output would go to that file, so the `echo` line becomes:

```
echo "$(date +'%d.%m.%Y;%H:%M:%S;')$line"
```

#### Amended answer

The question was originally missing lots of key information.  It eventually got updated to include the complete code.

The problem I identified originally remains an issue, but you weren't running into it because the input redirection was not working.  If you want the input to come from a process, use a pipe, or possibly [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution).  However, note that you have `#!/bin/sh` as your shebang line, and `/bin/sh` won't recognized process substitution; either change the shebang or use the pipe notation.  Note that process substitution has advantages if the loop is setting variables that need to be accessed after the loop is complete.

```
$SOCAT $DEV$BAUD STDOUT |
while read -r line
do
    …
done
```

or

```
while read -r line
do
    …
done < <($SOCAT $DEV$BAUD STDOUT)
```

Note that your code contains the line:

```
PROG=$SOCAT $DEV$BAUD STDOUT
```

This runs the command identified by `$DEV$BAUD` with the argument `STDOUT` and the environment variable `PROG` set to the value of `$SOCAT`.  That is not what you wanted.

You could use an array:

```
PROG=($SOCAT $DEV$BAUD STDOUT)
```

and then run:

```
"${PROG[@]}"
```

either in the pipe line:

```
"${PROG[@]}" |
while read -r line
do
    …
done
```

or with process substitution:

```
while read -r line
do
    …
done < <("${PROG[@]}")
```

Note that unless there is code after the final `exec 0<&3`, there was no particular virtue in the redirections involving file descriptor 3.  You should also close 3 when you're done with it:

```
exec 0<&3 3>&-
```

---

The 'final' code includes the lines:

```
CMD="$SOCAT $DEV$BAUD STDOUT"

$CMD |
while read -r line
```

This works OK because there are no spaces in the arguments to the command.  That's a common case, but beware of spaces in arguments and file paths.

Comment: there is no error message... it just doesnt write to the textfile :/

the ; marks the column when I post the textfile to excel

Comment: That probably means, then, that the `exec 0<$prog` is leaving with you with an empty input, so the first `read` fails, so there's nothing to write to the file.

Comment: Thanks for the help. done < < ( $PROG ) causes Syntax error: redirection unexpected. The final code is in the first post

Comment: (1) You need to be careful with the spaces:  `done < <($PROG)` (enclose code in comments in backquotes so it is easier to read).  (2) Your shebang line (`#!/bin/sh`) says you're using `sh` instead of `bash` and `sh` doesn't recognize process substitution.  Change the `sh` to `bash`, or use the pipe notation I suggested instead (which, I see, is what you've done).

Comment: sorry, just wrote it here because I had the error copied. In the script I had it without that space. Good to know that you need bash for this, thanks for that info